# Why are 2 org.apache.hc.core5.http.Header not equal when created with the same content?

Tags: java, http-headers, junit5, equals, hashcode

Why does

```
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.Header;

Assertions.assertEquals(new BasicHeader("name", "value", true), new BasicHeader("name", "value", true));
```

or

```
Assertions.assertEquals(new BasicHeader("name", "value", false), new BasicHeader("name", "value", false));
```

fail the assertion?

It probably has somethin to do with different hashcodes being generated, but I fail to see - if it should be the reason - why it is like it is.

Comment: Does the class BasicHeader override equals? [From what I could find it doesn't seem to override equals](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-core/blob/master/httpcore5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/core5/http/message/BasicHeader.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BasicHeader` class does not override the **equals** method, so it uses the default implementation of the equals method from the Object class.

The default implementation of the equals method checks if two objects are the same **instance**, meaning that they have the same **memory address**.

Instead you can make assertion element by element, example:

```
BasicHeader header1 = new BasicHeader("name", "value", true);
BasicHeader header2 = new BasicHeader("name", "value", true);

assertEquals(header1.getName(), header2.getName());
assertEquals(header1.getValue(), header2.getValue());
assertEquals(header1.isSensitive(), header2.isSensitive());
```

Note: there are other ways.

Comment: thanks for the quick and clean answer.